# Automatic Polling for changed Docker Images on Artifactory from Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, artifactory

Is there a way in which we can poll for latest docker images in artifactory through Jenkins in the trigger section for a deployment Job.

Use Case :
1.Writing a Kubernetes deployment job via Jenkins which will get triggered when we have the latest docker images in the artifactory repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URLTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/URLTrigger+Plugin) to achieve polling for your artifactory deployments.

For Artifactory you can watch the JSON response changes for files in a particular repo by USING REST API.

You can configure the FileList API for your Artifactory, that comes in the below format:

`http://org.server.com/artifactory/api/storage/<PATH_TO_FOLDER_OR_REPO>/`

This returns a JSON response like this:

```
{
"uri": "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme",
"created": ISO8601,
"files" : [
  {
  "uri": "/archived/doc1.txt",
  "size": "253100", //bytes
  "lastModified": ISO8601,
  "folder": "false",
  "sha1": sha1Checksum,
  "mdTimestamps": { "properties" : lastModified (ISO8601) }
  },...
]
}
```

So if there is a change in your repo, the JSON response will change and this plugin will compare the responses and trigger your Jenkins job.